# Python - Can't apply Data Validation to column group

Tags: python, validation, pandas.excelwriter

I am exporting a Excel file with a drop-down list.

For that I am using the code below:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('draft.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name='Filter', index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Filter']
    worksheet.data_validation('B:B', {'validate': 'list', 'source': ['open', 'high', 'close']})
```

I am putting the group'B:B' because I want the drop-down list on all values from the column.

However, when I run this I am getting this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Is that possible to apply Data Validation on all the column values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range 'B:B' isn't supported syntax. You need to specify the entire column range. Like this:

```py
    worksheet.data_validation('B1:B1048576', 
                              {'validate': 'list', 
                               'source': ['open', 'high', 'close']})
```

See also: [XlsxWriter - Row and Column Ranges](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#row-and-column-ranges).